# xfce in xubuntu_desktop

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

My question is not actually related to window appearance, icons and installed themes. I do not know why, but xubuntu is really more pretty that standart xfce as for me. All icons in panels looks smaller unlike standart xfce. As I found on my linux mint machine, big number of unity packages were installed like dependency to ubuntu desktop.
So my question is :

1. Is it real to make starndart xfce env so pretty like in xubuntu, but without installation xubuntu desktop?
2. How to do it ?

Regards!

Comment: The Xubuntu themes can be installed using the [`xubuntu-artwork`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xubuntu-artwork) package. After that you'll have to set the themes, wallpapers, etc. yourself, probably.

Answer (score 0):

There is some quite good directions at the following link:

http://www.howtogeek.com/193129/how-to-install-and-use-another-desktop-environment-on-linux/

But to give you some description, you can install practically any desktop that you like, and can even select to use different ones at the login screen.

You can install a new desktop environment by searching for it in the Software Centre or you can install it from the terminal with:

sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop

The example above should install the exact xubuntu desktop. If you install multiples and want to get rid of some, that can also be done through the software centre or by running (to uninstall the example above):

sudo apt-get remove xubuntu-desktop

Hope that helps.